# Python Re- match exact string with pattern

Tags: python, python-re

`string1="block12emp"`

`string2="block12"`

`reg=re.match('^[\D]{2,6}[\d]{2}\D{3}$', string1) # returns, block12emp`

The above regex works correctly

`reg=re.match('^[\D]{2,6}[\d]{2}\D{3}$', string2) # returns, block12`

Here, the excepted output for string2 is Null, but the regex returns `block12`

This regex will not match the full pattern, and returns only what matches in the string

How to match the string excatly with this pattern

Thanks

Comment: You last piece of code outputs nothing in my hands, not "block12".

Comment: It gives the correct result.. for string1, block12emp, for string2 nonetype my re version: 2.2.1 and python: 3.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i have checked on your pattern and it seems to be valid and working
so i tried to check it myself on python shell and it stills works

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>>
>>> string1 = "block12emp"
>>>
>>> string2 = "block12"
>>>
>>>
>>> reg_pattern = '^[\D]{2,6}[\d]{2}\D{3}$'
>>>
>>> res1 = re.match(reg_pattern, string1)
>>> res2 = re.match(reg_pattern, string2)
>>>
>>>
>>> res1.group()
'block12emp'
>>> res2.group()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

and this works as expected so when re.match find a string matching the pattern it returns it else it returns None

re-check how your logic deals with the exception and what exactly you return